Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'AppServices.Startup'.'
In the .NET 6 to .NET 8 migration projects, the WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) is replaced by Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args); and the associated changes are done.
The project has been upgraded to .NET 8 now.
Here is the Program.cs
public class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    WebHostBootstrapper.Bootstrap<Startup>(args);
   }
 }

Here is the Bootstrap method in WebHostBootstrapper class
        public static void Bootstrap<TStartup>(string[] args) where TStartup : CommonStartup
          {
            var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
                services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
                 services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, 
                 LoggerFactory>();
                 services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
                 services.AddLogging();
            });

            // Configure Logging
            builder.ConfigureLogging((ctx, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddConfiguration(ctx.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            });

            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Console.WriteLine("Configuring to Use DbConfigurationSource.");
                config.Add(new DbConfigurationSource()
                {
                    ConnectionFactory = DbConfigurationFactory
                }
                );
               
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.local.json", optional: true);
            });
            
            builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>(); 
            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            host.Run();
    }

Here is the Startup class
  public class Startup : CommonStartup
  {
  private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _currentEnvironment;
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,
      IWebHostEnvironment currentEnvironment,
      ILoggerFactory factory) : base(factory)
  {
      _currentEnvironment = currentEnvironment;
      Configuration = configuration;
  }
  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddBiisaServicesCommon(x =>
      {
          if (_currentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
          {
              x.SetUserAuthContextServiceType<DebugUserAuthService>();
          }

          x.ConfigureAppServices<UtilsController>()
              .ConfigureCore<IUtilsRepository>()
              .ConfigureInfrastructure<UtilsRepository>();
      });

      services.AddOptions();
      services.AddAppSettings<ICommonSettings, CommonSettings>();

      services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
      services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));

      services.AddControllers(opt =>
      {
          opt.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
      });
  }

}
But the application is throwing the below error in the var host = builder.Build(); line in the Bootstrap() method.
'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'AppServices.Startup'

    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; is added in the Startup class but still the issue is not resolving.

What is missing here?

I don't see a call to AddLogging

Added the below lines in the BootStrap() method
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
services.AddLogging();
But still same error.

Please [edit] your question with clarifications; do not just add code to comments.

Hey @HereticMonkey I already did. Please check my comment again. It is clearly state where the lines are added.
